# Should my database be exposed by REST API

Tags: asp.net, spring, rest, asp.net-web-api

Considering I have just one table named entity, it's a REST heresy to have an /entity URI to serve some fields of this table and another /entity/id/details path  to share a complete, or more large, representation of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your requirement.

A good start could be exposing [standard methods](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/standard_methods) to the `/entities` resource,
and implementing the [Partial Response](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/design_patterns#partial_response) pattern via `?fields` property.

**Example:**
In the case of Entity fields being: id, name, description

```
/entities/{id}?fields=id,name
```

would return a resource containing id and name only

Comment: I got it, but what if I don't want to expose the columns of my table by those fields parameter? It's a problem to make the client to trust there is a second resource named details?